# How to integrate Ros services in my Angular Web-App

Tags: angular, ros

I'm trying to establish a communication between a robot arm built on ros melodic and my web-app.

On the web-app side, I have my gui without logic in a localhost. On ROS side I have finalized all the movements, I want to integrate, in a C++  program.

Right now I communicate with the robot through ssh command to establish a communication. And to move the robot I run the name of the function with parameters in the terminal shell. (I don't use rqt,rviz, etc)

Could someone tells me how to establish a communication through my web-app in this same way so that when clicking on my "move" button, the logic calls the function?

I'm pretty new to stackOverflow so I'm sorry if this is not the right way to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you to use [rosnodejs](http://wiki.ros.org/rosnodejs). It is a interface to ROS written in NodeJS (Javascript). With NodeJS you can then program a server with an API which would accept your commands from your web-app (either through HTTP, websockets, ...). On the server side you then implement communication to ROS by using rosnodejs. You can use topics, services, well, whatever you want.